# Can you access the address book using CS5 when building an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, flash-cs5

I would like to develop a simple contact list iPhone application in Flash CS5.

I'm a web developer, and I have no experience with iPhone yet.

- How can I save the data of contacts? As I know, flash just post the data to a page, but what page, if it is an app?
- It's a off-line app, where the database should be?

Comment: iPhone/iOS/iPod Touch doesn't support Adobe flash. So I am not sure what is your question.

Comment: You are right. Flash CS5 can create a package for iOS devices. http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash CS5 Packager for iPhone doesn't support the [Address Book Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007212) on iOS. The [Packager for iPhone only support the following native iOS API](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Packager_for_iPhone%3aDeveloper_FAQ#Which_native_iOS_APIs_and_functionality_are_supported_when_using_Flash_tooling.3F):

- MultiTouch
- Screen Orientation
- Saving images to Photo Library
- Accelerometer
- Geo-location
- Cut / Copy / Paste